# sweetalert2 scaling issue on macbook pro

Tags: sweetalert2

A client has swals like this on his 2021 MBP using an external monitor. I don't have access to it and have not been able to reproduce on my hardware. Has anyone seen something this before? The screen shot is taken from the swal2 homepage using latest chrome version.
[image]